# No picture with S-Video

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have bought an S-Video cable so as that my old TV can be used as a second monitor, for watching iPlayer etc. I have an S-Video to Scart adaptor for the TV, Ubuntu knows there is a TV there and has set the correct resolution, but the TV shows no Picture??

Comment: Do you mind providing details about your hardware? Graphics card brand name and model. nVidias usually needs the hardware to be connected before booting, the BIOS using the right video output and a need to set the graphics profile at nvidia-settings X-Server configuration, I am not sure if the profile will remain after the reboot.

Answer (score 2):

NVIDIA GPU-based graphics cards with a TV-Out connector can use a television as another display device (the same way that it would use a CRT or digital flat panel). The TV can be used by itself, or in conjunction with another display device in a TwinView or multiple X screen configuration. If a TV is the only display device connected to your graphics card, it will be used as the primary display when you boot your system (i.e. the console will come up on the TV just as if it were a CRT).

[Ubuntu Forums Configuring and Enabling TV out on Nvidia](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=665704)

[Configuring TV-Out Nivdia](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/173.14.09/README/chapter-16.html)